# How to get OS language using C++ API?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, internationalization

I am in the process of developing a application which displays dialogs depending on the OS language. How I can get the OS language using C++ or Windows APIs (Windows 2008/Vista/7)?

Comment: Hi,
I have tried to create application using "GetUserDefaultLocaleName". But i am getting below errors during compilation.
error C3861: 'GetUserDefaultLocaleName': identifier not found
I have tried including "Windows.h" and "Winnls.h". No improvements in this case also..
Plz help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, int main() 
{ 
LPWSTR lpLocaleName=NULL; cout<<"Calling GetUserDefaultLocaleName"; int ret = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(lpLocaleName,LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH); return 0; 
} 
This is the program i wrote, when i run this exe on Windows 2008 exe crashes. Can anyone please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several functions to do this in Windows, depending on what format you want the information in.  Prior to Windows Vista, the language information was encoded into a LCID (Locale Id) which includes language, as well as some information about sorting and formatting.

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, a more flexible system called Locale Names was devised. 
[GetSystemDefaultLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318122(VS.85).aspx)

Use this if you want to work on Win2k and WinXP.
[GetSystemDefaultLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318121(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi, I have tried to create application using "GetUserDefaultLocaleName". But i am getting below errors during compilation. error C3861: 'GetUserDefaultLocaleName': identifier not found I have tried including "Windows.h" and "Winnls.h". No improvements in this case also.. Plz help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must be using recent versions of the windows header files (Visual Studio 2008 or 2010) and you need to `#define WINVER 0x0600` or larger, otherwise the header files won't let you access API's that aren't available before windows Vista.

Comment: Hi,
int main()
{
  LPWSTR lpLocaleName=NULL;
  cout<<"Calling GetUserDefaultLocaleName";
int ret = GetUserDefaultLocaleName(lpLocaleName,LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH);
return 0;
}

This is the program i wrote, when i run this exe on Windows 2008 application crashes. Can anyone please help!!
Thanks in advance
Santhos

Comment: The default locale is not the system language! It is common for them to be different.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to this question is wrong. You should **not** make user interface decisions based on the default locale. Use `GetDefaultUILanguage` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you resolve this problem?
If answer is No,
`LPWSTR lpLocalName=NULL` is wrong.
`LPWSTR lpLocalName=NULL` ----> `WCHAR localName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH]` is right.
Because No memory allocation is in `GetUserDefaultLocalName`.